# JQGrid default Search Dialog, input fields width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

Is there any option available in Jqgrid default search dialog to increase the width of the text box in search.

Here is the Image:

[image: Search Box]

**Updated** Code for my search is as below:

```
jQuery("#subscriptions").jqGrid(
    'navGrid',
    '#pager',
    { del: false, add: false, edit: false },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
        multipleSearch: true,
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        beforeShowSearch: function ($form) {
            $(".searchFilter table td .input-elm").attr('style', 'width:400px');
            $('#searchmodfbox_subscriptions').width(750);
            return true;
        },
        afterRedraw: function ($form) {
            $(".searchFilter table td .input-elm").attr('style', 'width:400px');
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I am also using loadonce option as true in my grid therefore all my search is local and no server call is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the style using the **beforeShowSearch** & **afterRedraw** event.

> beforeShowSearch fires every time before the search dialog is
>   shown and afterRedraw is fired when new search parameters are added.

I've modified the code with that. `$(".searchFilter table td .input-elm")`
Where ***searchFilter*** is the class of the parent div and ***input-elm*** is the class of the text box. 300px is just a number I gave, feel free to change it to accommodate your change:

```
jQuery("#subscriptions").jqGrid(
    'navGrid',
    '#pager',
    { del: false, add: false, edit: false },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
        multipleSearch: true,
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        beforeShowSearch: function($form) {
           $(".searchFilter table td .input-elm").attr('style','width:300px');
           return true;
        },
        afterRedraw: function($form) {
          $(".searchFilter table td .input-elm").attr('style','width:300px');
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @avijendr but after adding beforeShowSearch my search dialog is not opening. I check in chrome console and there is also no error.

Comment: @nido - it's a bug in jqgrid(introduced in 4.4). I updated the answer You will have to return true inside the beforeShowSearch. Please let me know if that works. It works for me locally!

Comment: One more thing; for the first time it did increased the length of the input field but when I changed the search criteria, it moved it back to its original size, can it be updated for all?

Comment: @nido I'll get back on that shortly.

Comment: @nido I've updated the answer with the solution. The trick is done by the "afterRedraw" event. I'd suggest you to keep a common function for changing the size and call it on both the events.

Comment: That didn't worked. No error and also I tried to debug in chrome but pointer never go in to afterRedraw option.

Comment: @nido - please post your code. It definitely works for me locally.

Comment: @avidendr - I have added the updated code in my main question, and the behavior is like, when there is only 1 search filter available and I select a different value from drop down then text shrinks to its original size, however if i add one more filter then the size remain as it is.... strange behavior...

Comment: @nido - strange. I'll have a look into it and update the answer. Thanks.