# JQGrid Search Dialog: text input resizes when selecting column from droplist

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid's search dialog box and resizing the text input in the beforeShowSearch and afterRedraw events as per this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355236/jqgrid-default-search-dialog-input-fields-width).

That works great on the initial load and reset, however, as mentioned in the comments of that post's answer, the text input resizes its width to default when a new value is chosen from the column droplist.  How does one maintain the width of the text input upon selection of a new droplist item?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution.  If anyone knows of another way, please contribute.  Here is what I did:  I attached an .change() function to the droplist.  This function sets the width value of the textbox, effectively keeping it in place.  To ensure the droplist exists when setting the .change() function I set it in the same function call from the beforeShowSearch event.  Here's the code:

```
$(divId).jqGrid('navGrid', pagerId, { add: true, edit: false, del: false, search: true },
        {}, //default for edit
        {}, //default for add
        {}, //delete disabled
        { //search
            width: '750',
            beforeShowSearch: function () {
                   //set textbox width
                   $(".searchFilter table td .input-elm").css('width', '300px');
                   //keep it in place with .change() on select
                   $(".searchFilter table td select").change(function () {
                        $(".searchFilter table td .input-elm").css('width', '300px');
                   });
                   return true;
        },
        {} // view parameters
    );
```

Of course, the duplication can be eliminated by extracting the .css call into its own function.  Refactor as you like.